EF Core PredicateBuilder negation
I'm using EF Core predicate builder to create a dynamic SQL statement. However, I'm finding it very difficult to figure out how to negate the expression. For example, I'm using a statement to figure out which locations are inside or outside a geographic bound.
The inclusion looks something like this:
insidePredicate = insidePredicate.And(myBounds.IncludedExpression());

The code that generates the included expression is just an extension method on the geobounds model:
    public static Expression<Func<MyLocation, bool>> IncludedExpression(this GeoBound geo)
    {
        return i => (geo.longitude <= i.Longitude && geo.latitude >= i.Latitude);
    }

While the include logic works fine, I'd like to invert that logic and NOT the selection, like this:
outsidePredicate = outsidePredicate.Not(myBounds.IncludedExpression());

This doesn't work, saying "no overload method for NOT takes one parameter". Except also does not do what I'd hope.
How can I invert this predicate expression with predicate builder?

What is outsidePredicate? Are you using LINQKit?

You can define an optional parameter to your method to signify its negation or the lack of it, like
    public static Expression<Func<MyLocation, bool>> IncludedExpression(this GeoBound geo, bool negated = false)
    {
        return i => ((geo.longitude <= i.Longitude && geo.latitude >= i.Latitude) != negated);
    }

This would actually make your method very powerful, because if you do not pass a logical value for negation, then it will assume that it was not negated, yet, if you pass a boolean value to it, then it will be properly handled.
This practice will allow you not to have to repeatedly infer negation at the code that calls it, but delegate it to the internal logic, it will make the code very readable as well as avoid having to define two methods for each predicate.
So it will keep your code shorter, more compact, more readable.

Assuming you are using PredicateBuilder from the LINQKit if you want to negate some predicate then just invoke the Not extension method which has only a single parameter (which would be outsidePredicate in case of outsidePredicate.Not call):
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Not<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr)

on the expression you want to be negated and then combine it with another via And or Or. For example if you want to negate myBounds.IncludedExpression() then the call would look like:
outsidePredicate = outsidePredicate.And(myBounds.IncludedExpression().Not());

